# JavaFX Sort Columns Row

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

i am currently working on a JavaFX Project. The goal of my Project is, to read files and display the values of the files in a TableView. The Columns of the TableView get created dynamically while runtime that means, i can´t create them with Scenebuilder and fix their position. Is there a way to Sort the columns in a custom order programmatically?

Comment: See [`TableView.getColumns`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getColumns--): "The TableColumns that are part of this TableView. As the user reorders the TableView columns, this list will be updated to reflect the current visual ordering. "

Comment: You simply need to make sure the `TableView.columns` list contains the elements in the correct order... There are implementations of sorting available in multiple places in the standard api, possibly the simplest being `tableView.getColumns().sort(comparator)`...

Comment: Thank you for these information. Should have checked that before. This solved most of my Problem. There is just one more thing left. I have 2 Columns, that contain Special values and i would like to place them as first and after that the other columns sorted alphabetically. Is there a way to place these first? Sorry for being such a noob :)